# Check if all words in a list appear as the start of at least one word in the words in another list

Tags: python

This works, but it seems overly complicated:

```
s1 = list(set(['red', 'gold', 'black', 'gold']))

s2 = ['golden', 'blackstone', 'golden', 'goldlike', 'blackstone', 'golden', 'redline', 'red']

lst = []
for i in s1:
    for j in s2:
        if j.startswith(i):
            lst.append(i)
lst2 = set(lst)
if len(s1) == len(lst2):
    print(s2)

# output: ['golden', 'blackstone', 'golden', 'goldlike', 'blackstone', 'golden', 'redline', 'red']
```

Is there a more efficient and compact way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is: Check if all words in a list appear as the start of at least one word in the words in another list.

Assuming that op wants all words in S1 to appear at least once as the beginning of an word in S2.

You can sort both input

```
def contain(s1, s2):
    count = 0
    for i in s1:
        while ( count < len(s2) and s2[count].startswith(i) == False ):
            count += 1
        if (count >= len(s2)): return False
    return True
s1 = sorted(set(['red', 'gold', 'black', 'gold', 'red', 're']))
s2 = sorted(['golden', 'blackstone', 'golden', 'goldlike', 'blackstone', 'golden', 'redline', 'red'])
print( contain(s1, s2) )
```

Output:

`True`

***Edit to include complexity:***

Let’s assume S1 has `n` elements and S2 has `m` elements.

A naive solution that have nested loops to iterate through both list will have the complexity of `O(n*m)`.

By sorting both S1 and S2 we can reduce the complexity of the solution.

Sort S1: `O(n*log n)`, Sort S2: `O(m*log m)` and Contain: `O(m)` (`m if m > n else n`)

As pointed out in the comments by Stefan, by sorting it will have better complexity than the naive approach.

Comment: I'd point out the better efficiency of this and say what this is doing. At first this just looked like a lot of code and I didn't feel like reading it, so I almost missed the efficiency advantage.

Comment: `n > m` can still lead to `True`, think of s1 being ['a', 'ab'] and s2 being ['ab']. And the complexities are ignoring the cost of comparing strings during sorting and in `startswith`, though I guess with "normal words" as input that's negligible (they'll differ early).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `all` and `any`:

```
s1 = set(['red', 'gold', 'black', 'gold'])
s2 = ['golden', 'blackstone', 'golden', 'goldlike', 'blackstone', 'golden', 'redline', 'red']
print(all(any(i.startswith(b) for b in s1) for i in s2))
```

Output:

```
True
```

Edit:

Checking if every element in `s1` appears in `s2`:

```
print(all(any(b.startswith(i) for b in s2) for i in s1))
```

Comment: Doesn't work, add `'foo'` to `s1` and watch this fail.

Comment: @StefanPochmann it would fail if we were checking if every element in `s1` occurred at the start of every element in `s2`, however, as the OP's question stands now, all we care about is ensuring that every element in `s2` starts with an element in `s1`.

Comment: How? It just is. Read their question again and read their code again. You're solving the wrong problem.

Comment: Oh, actually you maybe don't see the real problem, I misread you and thought you had said *"if every element in s1 occurred at the start of **some** element in s2"* instead of the *"if every element in s1 occurred at the start of **every** element in s2"* that you actually said (I guess I misread that because that doesn't make any sense).

Comment: @Ajax: The OP code checks that every element of `s1` got used.  Try adding "green" to `s2` and run it through both your code and OP's.  Perhaps you got fooled because OP prints `s2` for some reason.

Comment: @StefanPochmann the logic does not look quite correct to me, as it would make more sense to check the list with the target values first, however, I will add a shorter version of what specifically the OP posted.

Comment: The context for printing s2: I want to sift through thousands of lines and collect/print the matches.